# 5v dc drops to 2v when applied to L293d

Tags: dc-motor, driver

I have a 5v dc supply generated from voltage divider and this 5v is used to drive L293d.

But the problem is as soon as 5v supply is given to L293d the voltage drops to less than 2v.

what could be the problem??

Comment: The problem is that you are using a voltage divider as a power source. You can't.

Comment: but i also tried with 7805 where the voltage drops to 3v

Comment: Just a 7805, or a 7805 and its required support capacitors?

Comment: 7805 along with cap

Comment: Yes. Support caps are necessary to maintain output stability. Not optional! Also make sure the input voltage to the 7805 is more than the dropout. So > 7V or so.

Comment: when l293d is not connected 7805 gives around 5.12v but when L293d is connected the voltage drops to 3v

Comment: @carveone You took the words right out of my mouth. My next questions were going to be "what is your power source" and "can you show us your full schematic".

Comment: Yes show us a full diagram of your circuit, including what the input power supply is (voltage, current output rating) and exactly what the load on the L293D is (what is the motor? have you got a link to the part online?)

Answer (score 2):

The L293D has separate supplies for logic (pin 16) and H-bridge (pin 8). Use a 7805 to power the logic, and power the H-bridge straight from your power source. If you power the H-bridge from the 7805, then the 7805 will overheat and go into shutdown.

Comment: Depends on the load device, could be a tiny little motor.

Comment: The comments on the original question suggest that the load is sufficient to overload the 7805.

Comment: No, I have re-read the comments and cannot find suggestions of this. The 7805 can sag not due to it's load, but the fact the entire input supply sags (whether or not the 7805 was there). It sagged under a voltage divider, AND with a 7805, so there may be something else at play we don't know yet.

Comment: Drawing too much current from a 7805 (or generating too much heat in it) will cause its output to sag. But you're right, a weak power source could also cause the issue.